# Is it possible to overwrite scalar types in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I want an ID scalar to serialize data not as a string but rather as a Mongo Object id. The default behaviour is serializing data as a string. I don't want to create a custom scalar with another name as it may create some difficulties down the road.

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` type [is required to serialize as a string](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-ID), but absolutely nothing is specified about its format and it's intended to be opaque.  You could use a [Mongo object ID hex string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#specify-a-hexadecimal-string) as a GraphQL ID and (at a GraphQL level) there wouldn't be any problems with this.